# Angular 4 scroll with arrow keys from text field to <li>

Tags: html, angular, uitextfield, angular2-template

I am trying to implement a google like search field, i have partially managed but what i cant make work is the arrow scrolling possibility.
I would like, same as in their search field, to be able to scroll through the search result list with the arrow keys from the search field:
[image]

What i have so far is the following:

```
    <div>
    <div class="searcher">
            <input name="term" #term class="ng-valid ng-touched" size="60"
              placeholder="Start typing something...." (keyup)="invokeAutoSuggest(term.value)" (click)="showElement = !showElement">
          <br/>
       </div>
       </div>
     <div id="autosuggestBox" class="autoSuggestGoogleLike" [hidden]="!showElement">
          <div class="autoSuggestDiv" *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions" (click)="searchFromAutosuggest(suggestion.type,suggestion.value)" (click)="showElement = !showElement">
              {{suggestion.type}}:{{suggestion.value}}
            </div> 
       </div>
```

The css:

```
.autoSuggestGoogleLike{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:3;
    background-color : white;
    margin-left:-228px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

So `searcher` is the text field, and `autosuggestBox` the placeholder showing the results as list, i would like to be able to click the down arrow from the `searcher` text field and access the results.
Any advice?
Does it have to do with relationship between the divs?

Comment: You could try like this http://jsfiddle.net/6aj7t/23/
You can write a custom directive and put it on your parent div.Even thoug jsfiddle is using jquery you can convert it into plain javascript

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the `keyCode` first in your `invokeAutoSuggest` function, to detect up/down keypress then based on these you can increase/decrease the `activeIndex`. Like this ...

**In component**

```
...
private activeIndex: number = 0;

public invokeAutoSuggest(ev: Event) {
   if (38 === ev.keyCode) {
     return this.prevActiveMatch();
   }
   if (40 === ev.keyCode) {
     return this.nextActiveMatch();
   }
   // your code ...
}
public nextActiveMatch() {
  this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex < this.list.length - 1 ? ++this.activeIndex : this.activeIndex;
}
public prevActiveMatch () {
  this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex > 0 ? --this.activeIndex : 0;
}
...
```

**In template**

```
    ...
    <div class="searcher">
      <input name="term" #term class="ng-valid ng-touched" size="60"
              placeholder="Start typing something...." (keyup)="invokeAutoSuggest($event)" (click)="showElement = !showElement">
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="autoSuggestDiv" *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions; let i = index" (click)="searchFromAutosuggest(suggestion.type,suggestion.value)" (click)="showElement = !showElement" [ngClass]="{active: i===activeIndex}">
      {{suggestion.type}}:{{suggestion.value}}
    </div> 

...
```

To see the selected list item

```
styles: [`
.active {
      background: blue;
      color: white;
    }
`]
```